# How reliable is DRb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drb

Are there any issues to consider when using [DRb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/drb/rdoc/index.html) for implementing an in-memory message queue and for synchronizing actions between processes?  I heard that it could be unreliable, but haven't found anything on the web that confirms this assertion.

In case it's relevant, these would be processes running with a rails app environment that will update models in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DRb is pretty established and widely used. I don't know of anything that would make it unreliable, but I don't use it as a message queue

I'd say you'll have more luck using a message queue as a message queue, instead of rolling your own using DRb. There's a bunch of solutions depending on your needs, memcacheq is pretty easy to interact with, and is in-memory, and is pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use DRb running in two separate processes on my web server one to [perform minutes-long calculations, allowing the website to poll and check in on the progress](http://phrogz.net/drb-server-for-long-running-web-processes), another as a shared captcha server with its own DB connection for various applications on my server. In neither case have I ever had the DRb server fail (except where it was a programming mistake on my part).

Even when the DRb server does fail, you can restart it and the still-running client will reconnect cleanly the next time it needs to communicate.